# On page refresh avoid re-running a Jquery slide down/up function.

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have made a simple Jquery slide down/up function that triggers when scroll is above and under 40. That seems to work decent, but if I refresh the page when i scrolled to bottom at page etc the script re-runs the animation and sometimes it just show as initial state, and I have to scroll again to hide the top header division.

Is there an option to avoid this? Some kind of "if the scroll interaction is over 40 it wont trigger.

Tips / help much appreciated.

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 40){
            $(".header-top").slideUp();
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 40) {
            $(".header-top").slideDown();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried hiding by default with css and trigger scroll right after the handler is declared

Comment: Nope, don't know how to set that up :/ I'll make some searches for it.

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function(){/* code*/}).scroll()` ... the last part triggers the event to happen right away and thus will run the code inside the handler for that event

Comment: It still triggers the slide if you refresh after the 40 points. So you get the slide down and up effect and it returns to slided up state as supposed. It is just that effect flicking that really looks stupid.